# AWS API Gateway RestAPI CloudFormation update does not update Deployment resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

When I update a RestApi resource using CloudFormation update-stack, it does not update the corresponding Deployment resource.

My initial stack looks like this

```
   Resources :
      RestApi 
         /create
         /delete
      Deployment
         DependsOn = RestApi 
         stage = latest
```

I updated the stack looks like this

```
Resources :
  RestApi 
     /create
     /delete
     /update
  Deployment
     DependsOn = RestApi 
     StageName = latest
```

Using AWS cloudformation update-stack the RestApi is updated but deployment is not updated.  I have to manually went in Console and Redeploy the API with the same StageName.  Is it a known issue?

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue with cloudformation. Its frequently discussed on the forum https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=718403#718403

You can create a stage resource separately (not within a deployment resource) and then reference the latest deployment

```
Stage:
   Deployment: Ref Deployment1
Deployment1:
   RefApiId: RestApi
```

then when you update the configuration you can add a new deployment. This will associate the latest changes with the stage.

```
Stage:
   Deployment: Ref Deployment2
Deployment2:
   RefApiId: RestApi
```

Note that you still need to use the DependsOn field to wire them up correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  With this approach I think you will need to use different StageName for Stage resource for every update.  Otherwise, cloudformation will not recognize the change.  Then your gateway URL will change every updates (unless we use custom domain).

Comment: Your url should not change. This will cause cloudformation to create a new deployment and associate it with an existing stage.